# Dataproc spark job (long running) on cloudrun on Gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, architecture, google-cloud-run, orchestration, dataproc

I had a small doubt to clarify as an expert advice
Can I run dataproc (pyspark job) an an image on cloud run (service or job) as dataproc job may take few minutes to hours to complete so it will asynchronous orchestration and it can be batch or event both either trigger by rest api or by a event from pubsub

Hope you understand my query,

Options (1 and 2 point is more costly compared to 3rd - I feel)

1. Run dataproc job using composer (composer will be on during idle state with autoscaling also)
2. Run on gke autopilot (again it will be custom image of spark job)
3. Run on cloud run (service if finish within 60 mins or as a job if takes few hours) will charge based on number of requests.

Requirement is dataproc spark jobs (workflow-ephemeral) will run demand basis ( it may run based on request per day) hence thinking to use cloud run

In cloudrun jobs can be executed using workflow dependencies/batch scheduling on scheduler/for event can use eventarc

Best architecture decision

Comment: You don't ask the right question. Dataproc, and GKE if you can run a spark job on Kubernetes (with Flink for instance), are a cluster: you can run your job on multiple node (VM) and parallelize the process. Cloud Run job is more single threaded (which is wrong because you can have task (instances) in parallel, but it's not based on a distributed computing system like Dataproc or Flink). Anyway, there is no problem to run a single container on any platform (even Cloud Build is you wish!!), But, for distributing computing, choose the right one!